# Navigation Menu sticking in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css, navigationbar

I'm making a very simple website for a business (and I'm kind of new to this field), my menu is working fine in every browser except IE where when hovering over the link it keeps an active look. I'm using HTML5 and CSS3.

HTML

```
    <nav><ul>
        <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="corporate.html">Corporate Info</a></li>
        <li><a href="employment.html">Employment</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">
        Login</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Forums</a></li>
    </ul></nav>
```

CSS

```
    .main-header nav {
    background-color: #DCDCDC;
    height: 40px;
}

.main-header nav ul{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.main-header nav ul li {
    float: left;
    display: inline;
}

.main-header nav a:link, .main-header nav a:visited {
    color: #023878;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    height: 20px;
}

.main-header nav a:hover, .main-header nav a:active,
.main-header nav .active a:link, .main-header a:visited {
    background-color: #B6C2C7;
    color: #023878;
    text-shadow: none;
}

.main-header nav ul li a {
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to the Home link?  If so, the *active* class applied to the li element is what does that.  You can add the active class to show which page you're on currently.  Try removing the active class and see if that does what you're looking for.  So, change this line in the HTML:

```
<li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
```

to this:

```
<li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
```

Comment: No, it's supposed to be that way, sorry should have clarified, and when you click the "corporate info" link and are on that page the active link changes to "corporate info" so it stays lit. But on IE all of the button are acting as if they're active at the same time.

Comment: Is that snippet of HTML you posted copied from a view source of the page when you're having the problem?

Comment: Yes, that HTML5 and CSS3 is mine, it's supposed to work kind of like the dictionary.com site, when you're on the home page it stays highlighted, then you go to corporate - home unhighlights and corporate highlights - so on and so forth. When you hover they also light up but the page you're on stays highlighted. I've updated the code a bit and none of them stay highlighted in IE anymore, but the page I'm currently on doesn't stay lit either. Oh and it only happens in IE(11)